# How to get elm to display HTML from an ajax call

Tags: elm

I have the following Elm code, it is doing an Ajax call which will return some HTML which I want to embed directly into the dom. The problem is that the code here escapes the html so the user sees the markup, not the intended result. So I need to replace plainText with something else, but I am at a loss as to what that would be

```
load_comp_from_comp_set : String -> Signal Element
load_comp_from_comp_set compset_id =
  Signal.constant ("http://localhost:8000/finch/compset/" ++ compset_id)
  |> Http.sendGet
  |> Signal.map (result >> plainText)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Markdown.toElement](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/elm-markdown/1.1.2/Markdown#toElement) from the [elm-markdown library](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/elm-markdown/latest). I tried this the following code on [elm-lang.org/try](http://elm-lang.org/try) and it injected the HTML as expected.

```
import Markdown

main = Markdown.toElement """
<div>
  <h1 style="display: inline">Hello!</h1>
  <span></span> <sub>world</sub>
</div>
"""
```

You can use [elm-package](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-package) to install the library so elm-make automatically picks it up. It should be as simple as `elm-package install evancz/elm-markdown`.

Comment: @ZacharyK Strange. I can't reproduce that problem with my little code example. elm-markdown is a thin wrapper around [marked](https://github.com/chjj/marked), so maybe you can find your problem in the issues there?